# how to store each json array in different SharedPref Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, sharedpreferences, storage

How Can I store each of my Json Array into different SharedPref in Android.

i.e.

I need to store each of the categories *[category_1] => Array* DATA into a SharedPref  to access it later.

How Can I run through the Json and store it into SharedPref. Thanks guys for your help.

**The Json:**

```
Array
(
    [status] => success
    [reason] => success
    [version] => 1
    [total] => Array
        (
            [category_1] => 3
            [category_2] => 3
            [category_3] => 3
        )

    [title] => Array
        (
            [category_1] => Food
            [category_2] => Drink
            [category_3] => Dessert
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [category_1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [content_id] => 123456
                            [name] => Name1
                            [title] => This is title one
                            [desc] => This is title description
                            [thumb] => http://image.jpg

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (...

                )

            [category_2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [content_id] => 123456
                            [name] => Name1
                            [title] => This is title one
                            [desc] => This is title description
                            [thumb] => http://image.jpg
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (...

                )

            [category_3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [content_id] => 123456
                            [name] => Name1
                            [title] => This is title one
                            [desc] => This is title description
                            [thumb] => http://image.jpg
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                       ( ...


                )

        )

)
```

**UPDATED** **__________________________**

I used it :

```
                    SharedPreferences sharedCategory_1Pref = getSharedPreferences(CATEGORY_1, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    Editor editor = sharedCategory_1Pref.edit();
                    editor.putString(CATEGORY_1, jArray_data_category_1.toString());
                    //System.out.println(jArray_data_category_1.toString());
                    editor.commit();
```

I am able to save the json array into the SharePref. But now I can't read it, using this:

```
                     try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray2 = new JSONArray(sharedCategory_1Pref.getString(CATEGORY_1, status));
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.length(); i++) {
                                 Log.d("your JSON Array", jsonArray2.getInt(i)+"");

                                 Log.e("inside try", "inside try");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("inside Exception", "inside Exception");
                        }
```

I keeping going into the Exception.
Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: I make another question with more details , thanks for your help so far. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260456/how-to-save-a-json-array-into-sharedpreferences-and-read-again-in-a-different-ac)

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide your desired output, it will be easy for us to help you. However you will end up in doing something like the following.

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

editor.putString(KEY1, first_json_array_as_string);
editor.putString(KEY1, second_json_array_as_string);
.....
editor.commit();
```

Your can loop through your categories array also. Share your required output format to get better help.

Comment: Is the answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260456/how-to-save-a-json-array-into-sharedpreferences-and-read-again-in-a-different-ac/25279754#25279754 helpful for you