# How to save a JSON array into SharedPreferences and read again in a different activity. Android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, sharedpreferences

I need to save my Json Array into SharedPreferences and access it later in different  Activity.

here is the example of my **Json**:

```
Array
(
    [status] => success
    [reason] => success
    [version] => 1
    [total] => Array
        (
            [category_1] => 3
            [category_2] => 3
            [category_3] => 3
        )

    [title] => Array
        (
            [category_1] => Food
            [category_2] => Drink
            [category_3] => Dessert
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [category_1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [content_id] => 123456
                            [name] => Name1
                            [title] => This is title one
                            [desc] => This is title description
                            [thumb] => http://image.jpg

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (...

                )

            [category_2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [content_id] => 123456
                            [name] => Name1
                            [title] => This is title one
                            [desc] => This is title description
                            [thumb] => http://image.jpg
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (...

                )

            [category_3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [content_id] => 123456
                            [name] => Name1
                            [title] => This is title one
                            [desc] => This is title description
                            [thumb] => http://image.jpg
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                       ( ...
                )
        )
)
```

**MainActivity:**

```
...
try {

                        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
                        String status = jObject.getString("status");

                        if (status.equals("success")) {
                            // Log.e("status",status);

                            JSONObject jObject_data = new JSONObject(jObject.getString("data"));
                            JSONArray jArray_data_category_1 = new JSONArray(jObject_data.getString("category_1"));
                            JSONArray jArray_data_category_2 = new JSONArray(jObject_data.getString("category_2"));
                            //JSONArray jArray_data_category_3 = new JSONArray(jObject_data.getString("category_3"));



                            //Log.e("category_1 *****************************************", jArray_data_category_1.toString());
                            vc.insertCategory_1Pref(jArray_data_category_1.toString());
```

This is my **SharedPrefInput.java:**

```
...
public class SharedPrefInput {

    public static final String CATEGORY_1 = "CATEGORY_1";
    public static final String CATEGORY_2 = "CATEGORY_2";
    public static final String CATEGORY_3 = "CATEGORY_3";

...
```

Here is **VarController**

```
...
//category_1
        public void insertCategory_1Pref(String s){     
            prefSetting = context.getSharedPreferences(SharedPrefInput.DEVICE_SETTING, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            prefSettingEditor = prefSetting.edit();
            prefSettingEditor.putString(SharedPrefInput.CATEGORY_1, s);
            prefSettingEditor.commit();
        }

        public String readCategory_1Pref(){     
            prefSetting = context.getSharedPreferences(SharedPrefInput.DEVICE_SETTING, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            return prefSetting.getString(SharedPrefInput.CATEGORY_1, "00");
        }
...
```

And here is me trying to access it. but it don't work.

```
 try {
                                    JSONArray jsonArray2 = new JSONArray(sharedCategory_1Pref.getString(CATEGORY_1, status));
                                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.length(); i++) {
                                         Log.d("your JSON Array", jsonArray2.getInt(i)+"");

                                         Log.e("inside try", "inside try");
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Log.e("inside Exception", "inside Exception");
                                }
```

This is the **Log** when i try to read the SharePref :

```
08-12 09:22:34.757: W/System.err(871):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:96)
08-12 09:22:34.787: W/System.err(871):  at org.json.JSONArray.getInt(JSONArray.java:357)
08-12 09:22:34.787: W/System.err(871):  at com.example.brazilapps.MainActivity$1.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:158)
08-12 09:22:34.787: W/System.err(871):  at com.example.brazilapps.MainActivity$1.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
08-12 09:22:34.787: W/System.err(871):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
08-12 09:22:34.797: W/System.err(871):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
08-12 09:22:34.797: W/System.err(871):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
08-12 09:22:34.797: W/System.err(871):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 09:22:34.808: W/System.err(871):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-12 09:22:34.808: W/System.err(871):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-12 09:22:34.818: W/System.err(871):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 09:22:34.827: W/System.err(871):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-12 09:22:34.827: W/System.err(871):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-12 09:22:34.827: W/System.err(871):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-12 09:22:34.867: W/System.err(871):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 09:22:34.867: E/inside Exception(871): inside Exception
```

Comment: Simply save it as a string(json.toString) and retrieve it parse it. Are there any specific problems that you are facing in doing so?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Any error, exception? Please post the log entry. And it seems odd that you're calling vc.insertCategory_1Pref(...), but not vc.readCategory_1Pref().

Comment: /thank for ur comments. i added the error Log above.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest  you that when you get Result in JSON convert it into string

and store that string in shared preference as a string and use that string in activity during use convert that saved string into JSON object
using this line  `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);` and convert JSONObject into string using this line

```
    JSONObject foo = yourJSONOject;
String uid = foo.get("CNo").isString().toString();
String type = foo.get("CName").isString().toString();
```

or you can use **toString** to JSONObject so it will convert it into string

Answer (score 0):

Save the JSON as String using the [JSONArray.toString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#toString()) to the SharedPreferences using the [putString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and retrieve it later with the [getString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) then calling the [new JSONArray(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `jsonArray2.getInt(i)`, while it seems that you array consists of `JSONObject`s?

Try `jsonArray2.getJSONObject(i)` instead.

Also, this part of the code:

```
JSONArray jArray_data_category_1 = new JSONArray(jObject_data.getString("category_1"));
```

could be rewritten as

```
JSONArray jArray_data_category_1 = jObject_data.getJSONArray("category_1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON looks like and response from API/Webservices.

Why you want to store such response in Shared Preferences ?

I guess, Just to avoid same api request call in different activity ?

I would suggest you to implement caching like thing. Shared Preferences is not made for storing such big strings.

You can also store that json file in your files folder of your app and read that file whenever required. (Thats what caching does.)

Comment: My app, has 3 tabs, that display img for the food categories. so, I just want call the API once when the app is loaded  on the main Activity. then in each tab I just read the data from Shared Preferences

Comment: If you are hitting an API everytime app opens (Correct me if I am wrong), then in that case you should store data in some model class and use its object to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

Siince you are getting type mismatch in the `getInt()` line, instead of the line

```
Log.d("your JSON Array", jsonArray2.getInt(i)+"");
```

you can get it as string and parse it to int.

```
Log.d("your JSON Array", Integer.parseInt(jsonArray2.getString(i))+"");
```